# Recaptcha disappears during PostBack

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, recaptcha

I have seen a couple of other posts on here regarding the use of Recaptcha with ASP.net UpdatePanels but have not yet found an answer that solves my problem.

Here is my ASPX code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updRecaptcha" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="btnrecaptcha" runat="server" Theme="clean" PrivateKey"<%$ Resources: General, CaptchaPrivateKey %>" PublicKey="<%$ Resources: General, CaptchaPublicKey %>" />        
  <asp:Label ID="recaptchaerror" runat="server" style="color: Red;"/>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So the Recaptcha control lives within a user control that uses several .Net validation controls (e.g. RequiredFieldValidator).  I need to valdiate the Recaptcha and the ASP.net controls before allowing the process to continue.

If any of the validation fails (Recaptcha or .Net) then the Recaptcha control disappears.  Looking at the HTML source, the control isn't loading at all after the Postback - eventhough I am telling the UpdatePanel to update.

I can't reload the page completely as this all appears as an overlay on top of the page and there are other form fields on the page behind.

Please help!

**Edit:**

From C# when the Recaptcha fails I am calling this code :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "InvalidRecaptcha", "alert('Recaptcha Failed');Recaptcha.reload();alert('Recaptcha Reloaded');", true);
```

Both of the alert statements fire but the Recaptcha still does not load.

Comment: Do you have a link to a live demonstration of it ? I suspect that is not re-initialize the javascript after the post back.

Comment: Unfortunately not one that I can share.  I saw in Google Chrome's console tab that it was showing this error : Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget the ScriptManager. All you need is this script in the page. Change accordingly for your identifiers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// RECAPTURE CODE FOR RELOADING AFTER INCORRECT ENTRY
if (typeof Sys != 'undefined') {
    var requestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    requestManager.add_endRequest(function(sender, args) {

        $('<div id="recaptcha_widget_div"/>').appendTo('#recaptcha_widget_div2');

        if (typeof Recaptcha != 'undefined') {                                
            Recaptcha.create(recaptcha_key, "recaptcha_widget_div",
            {
                theme: "red",
                callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted solution did not work for me.  Here is the answer that I have tried and is working:

[ASP.Net, disappearing Recaptcha, UpdatePanels and Partial PostBacks: Fixed once and for all](http://www.5limes.com.au/blog/?p=55)

Basically it involves creating a hidden div and using jquery to re-render the html.  Also the blog post gives a nice little breakdown of the typical solutions (e.g., using RegisterClientScriptBlock with a simple reload) and why they fail.

```
<div runat="server" id="pbTarget" visible="false"></div>  
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server" Theme="clean" />
```

code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
  recaptcha.Validate();  
  if (!Page.IsValid || !recaptcha.IsValid)  
  {  
    pbTarget.Visible = true;  
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(  
      recaptcha,  
      recaptcha.GetType(),  
      "recaptcha",  
      "Recaptcha._init_options(RecaptchaOptions);"  
      + "if ( RecaptchaOptions && \"custom\" == RecaptchaOptions.theme )"  
      + "{"  
      + "  if ( RecaptchaOptions.custom_theme_widget )"  
      + "  {"  
      + "    Recaptcha.widget = Recaptcha.$(RecaptchaOptions.custom_theme_widget);"  
      + "    Recaptcha.challenge_callback();"  
      + "  }"  
      + "} else {"  
      + "  if ( Recaptcha.widget == null || !document.getElementById(\"recaptcha_widget_div\") )"  
      + "  {"  
      + "    jQuery(\"#" + pbTarget.ClientID + "\").html('<div id=\"recaptcha_widget_div\" style=\"display:none\"></div>');"  
      + "    Recaptcha.widget = Recaptcha.$(\"recaptcha_widget_div\");"  
      + "  }"  
      + "  Recaptcha.reload();"  
      + "  Recaptcha.challenge_callback();"  
      + "}",  
      true  
    );  

    return;  
  }  
  else  
  {  
    //normal page processing here...
```

Comment: Worked perfect for me when using an UpdatePanel

Comment: I have this embedded in an ascx control that wraps the form, including the recaptcha in an UpdatePanel.I get a console full of errors "Recaptcha not defined" (that's Recaptcha with a capital 'R')

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Recaptcha 2.0 this is your Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function CaptchaReload() {
          Recaptcha.create("yourpublicKey", 'yourRecaptchadiv', {
          theme: 'white',
          callback: grecaptcha.reset()

        });
      }
```

This is your recaptcha Div

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="yourPublicKey"></div>
```

Then at end of postback event  call the Javascript

```
 protected void txtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtEmail.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        ValidateEmail();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "CaptchaReload", "$.getScript(\"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js\", function () {});", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay. Your answer led me in the right direction except that in my case, the content was contained within an ajax updatepanel and you have to  use those references in the ScriptManager line as follows: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "CaptchaReload", "$.getScript(\"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js\", function () {});", true);

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I didn't need to apply the RegisterClientScriptBlock call to make it work. 
I just use:

> UpdateMode="Always"

for the updatepanel and on the server side I call:

```
updatePanel.Update();
```

This also prevents the captcha from displaying a new challenge.

Comment: Following your instructions, I got the following error message: "The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'sifCaptchaControl' when UpdateMode is set to Conditional."

Comment: You can't set an UpdatePanel's UpdateMode to "Always" and then manually call the .Update() function. It's one of the other.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is basically the same as "User" (*that* *worked* !), but to help anyone using VB.
I would have commented there, but I have zippo rep...
(hope this isn't too much of an infraction, and that it helps someone out)

I ported the meat of this to VB.NET:

```
pbTarget.Visible = True
        Dim _sb As New StringBuilder
        With _sb
            .Append("Recaptcha._init_options(RecaptchaOptions);")
            .Append("if ( RecaptchaOptions && ""custom"" == RecaptchaOptions.theme )")
            .Append("{")
            .Append("  if ( RecaptchaOptions.custom_theme_widget )")
            .Append("  {")
            .Append("    Recaptcha.widget = Recaptcha.$(RecaptchaOptions.custom_theme_widget);")
            .Append("    Recaptcha.challenge_callback();")
            .Append("  }")
            .Append("} else {")
            .Append("  if ( Recaptcha.widget == null || !document.getElementById(""recaptcha_widget_div"") )")
            .Append("  {")
            .Append("    jQuery(""#")
            .Append(pbTarget.ClientID)
            .Append(""").html('<div id=""recaptcha_widget_div"" style=""display:none""></div>');")
            .Append("    Recaptcha.widget = Recaptcha.$(""recaptcha_widget_div"");")
            .Append("  }")
            .Append("  Recaptcha.reload();")
            .Append("  Recaptcha.challenge_callback();")
            .Append("}")
        End With
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(recaptcha, recaptcha.[GetType](), "recaptcha", _sb.ToString, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work using version 2.1.0.0 of the reCAPTCHA library for .NET with webforms, script manager and inside an update panel.

First, in the .aspx page outside of the update panel I'm loading the Google reCAPTCHA library:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" 
            async defer></script>
```

Second, in the .aspx page inside the update panel I added a div that will work as the target panel to load the reCAPTCHA:

```
<div runat="server" id="pbTarget" visible="false"></div>
<cc1:Recaptcha ID="recaptcha" runat="server" Theme="Clean" />
```

Third, in the code behind at the end of my postback event I registered a startup script to render the reCAPTCHA in my target panel

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click
    pbTarget.Visible = True
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        UpdatePanel1,
        UpdatePanel1.GetType(),
        "loadCaptcha",
        "grecaptcha.render('" & pbTarget.ClientID & "', {'sitekey': 'YourKey' });",
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to reload reCaptcha control with javascript, try this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     btnrecaptcha.Validate();
     if(IsValid && updRecaptcha.IsValid}
     {
          //Some logic here
     }
     ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "CaptchaReload", "Recaptcha.reload();", true);
}
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar : 

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "InvalidRecaptcha", "alert('Recaptcha Failed');Recaptcha.reload();alert('Recaptcha Reloaded');", true);

Both alert statements fire off but the Recaptcha still does not load.

Comment: I had to abandon Recaptcha and use my own "prove you are human" question instead.  I would still like to know how to solve this though.